# Implementing a Log Out Button in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, tabbarcontroller

I have an iPad app with a log in screen view controller as the initial view.

When logged in, a tab bar controller appears with 3 view controller tabs. I want to add a 4th tab that will function as a log out button. How can I implement this?

I tried creating a custom tab bar controller class but I don't know what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another Item (`viewController`) inside the `UITabBarController`, add buttons or whatever you want to do logout functionality with. If you really have added 3 tabs then what is problem in adding 4th one?